# How to create delta table using Delta lake standalone and write data

Tags: java, scala, parquet, delta-lake

I am able to read delta table which is created in Amazon S3 using standalone api, but unable to create delta table and insert data to it. In below link for delta lake it is mentioned to use Zappy reader and writer which is fictitious and used as reference.

I tried using avro parquet writer but ran into issues in getting all the data needed for AddFile object, Could you please share any example for writer which can be used in scala and how to commit meta data to delta table?

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-standalone.html#-azure-blob-storage

```
ZappyDataFrame correctedSaleIdToTotalCost = ...;
ZappyDataFrame invalidSales = ZappyReader.readParquet(filteredFiles);
ZappyDataFrame correctedSales = invalidSales.join(correctedSaleIdToTotalCost, "id")

ZappyWriteResult dataWriteResult = ZappyWritter.writeParquet("/data/sales", correctedSales);
```

"Please note that this example uses a fictitious, non-Spark engine Zappy to write the actual parquet data, as Delta Standalone does not provide any data-writing APIs. Instead, Delta Standalone Writer lets you commit metadata to the Delta log after you’ve written your data"

Dependencies used - pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.12</version>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
      <artifactId>delta-standalone_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried using avro parquet writer but ran into issues in getting all the data needed for AddFile object, Could you please share any example for writer which can be used in scala and how to commit meta data to delta table?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell Delta standalone doesn't appear to support the actual creation of a Delta Table. From the documentation, we can see they state that:

> The Delta Standalone library is a single-node Java library that can be used to read from and write to Delta tables

This is a real shame and rather limits the functionality of the standanlone library. For example, if we look at the supported Hive connector, we can see the following in the [README file](https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/blob/master/hive/README.md):

> Right now the connector supports only EXTERNAL Hive tables. The Delta table must be created using Spark before an external Hive table can reference it.

Having said that, you can still use [DeltaTable](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/index.html) to create a table from existing Parquet files and then use Delta standalone to further interact with the table.

`delta-rs` the Rust implementation has full support for writing Delta Tables and interacting with them.

Comment: For me it was also a big disappointment. I was hoping I was going to be able to create Delta Lake tables with parquet from Sprint Boot. And the Zappy thing seems like a joke...

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to create a table using Delta Standalone, but it isn't obvious how to do it at all. Here is a short Java program that shows how to create a new table:

```java
package myproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import io.delta.standalone.DeltaLog;
import io.delta.standalone.Operation;
import io.delta.standalone.OptimisticTransaction;
import io.delta.standalone.actions.Action;
import io.delta.standalone.actions.AddFile;
import io.delta.standalone.actions.Metadata;
import io.delta.standalone.types.StringType;
import io.delta.standalone.types.StructField;
import io.delta.standalone.types.StructType;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter;

public class DeltaExample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
            .record("MyRecord")
            .namespace("mynamespace")
            .fields()
            .requiredString("myfield")
            .endRecord();
        ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(new Path("delta/file.parquet"))
            .withSchema(schema)
            .build();
        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("myfield", "myvalue");
        writer.write(record);
        long size = writer.getDataSize();
        writer.close();
        List<Action> actions = List.of(new AddFile("file.parquet", new HashMap<String, String>(), size, System.currentTimeMillis(), true, null, null));
        DeltaLog log = DeltaLog.forTable(new Configuration(), "delta");
        OptimisticTransaction txn = log.startTransaction();
        Metadata metaData = txn.metadata()
            .copyBuilder()
            .partitionColumns(new ArrayList<String>())
            .schema(new StructType()
                    .add(new StructField("myfield", new StringType(), true))).build();
        txn.updateMetadata(metaData);
        txn.commit(actions, new Operation(Operation.Name.CREATE_TABLE), "myproject");
    }
}
```